# Courier IMAP - Account's mailbox directory is not owned by the correct uid or gid

Tags: openbsd, imap

so i poked around and found out that `DEFDOMAIN="@domain.se"` is messing things up, so i removed that from `/etc/courier/imapd` and i got to the point where `SMTP` work and i get this from the `IMAP`:

```
Jul  2 13:23:10 HOST authdaemond: Authenticated: sysusername=anton, sysuserid=<null>, sysgroupid=20001, homedir=/storage/vmail/anton, address=anton, fullname=Anton, maildir=<null>, quota=<null>, options=<null>
Jul  2 13:23:10 HOST authdaemond: Authenticated: clearpasswd=MyPasswd, passwd=$3e$04$AC1c10x0A3etWCJFrla.Rl2sevNhq24yXYxrq8IN7mEeGI20.
Jul  2 13:23:10 HOST imapd-ssl: anton: Account's mailbox directory is not owned by the correct uid or gid
```

But i'm not sure why because:

```
# ls -l /storage/vmail/
-rw-r--r--  1 vmail  vmail   22 Mar 13 01:06 .Xdefaults
-rw-r--r--  1 vmail  vmail  773 Mar 13 01:06 .cshrc
-rw-r--r--  1 vmail  vmail  398 Mar 13 01:06 .login
-rw-r--r--  1 vmail  vmail  113 Mar 13 01:06 .mailrc
-rw-r--r--  1 vmail  vmail  218 Mar 13 01:06 .profile
drwx------  2 vmail  vmail  512 Jun 30 10:44 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x  3 anton  anton  512 Jun 30 10:44 anton
```

my `/etc/courier/imapd` says:

```
MAILDIRPATH=/storage/vmail
```

But i've also tried:

```
MAILDIRPATH=Maildir
```

And `/etc/passwd` states:

```
# cat /etc/passwd | grep anton                                                                                                                                                                                 
anton:*:20001:20001:Anton:/storage/vmail/anton:/sbin/nologin
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so the good guys over at [daemonforums.org](http://www.daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=7982) solved it for me!

Disabled `IMAP_MAILBOX_SANITY_CHECK=0` in `/etc/courier/imapd` and added that exact same line to `/etc/courier/imapd-ssl` did the trick.

Also not sure if it helped or if it would have worked anyway i did:
`maildirmake /storage/vmail/anton/Maildir` which is the Maildir for my account, obviously the path will differ from anyone tracing my footsteps in this issue.